# jquery, cycle through divs, then stop on last div?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I've been searching around, but haven't found something that actually works.

Basically we have an interstitial page that the user clicks a button.  I want to loop through background images, say 500ms each, then stop on the last div.

I've found a few things out there, but can't get anything to stop on the last one?  The ones I've played with doesn't seem to stop on the last one, it just keeps running.

Thanks in advance!

Here's the code, basically Slide1 will show up for 500ms, Slide2 for 500ms, then stop on slideMain:

```
 <div id="slideshow">
        <div id="slide1" class="active">Slide1</div>
        <div id="slide2">Slide2</div>
        <div id="slide3">Slide3</div>
        <div id="slide4">Slide4</div>
        <div id="slide5">Slide5</div>
        <div id="slide_main">SlideMain</div>
     </div>
```

Comment: How about showing us your code?

Comment: At least a small code sample/example would help. Also please define what you mean by "stop at the last one". Stop after the loop completes all your images? Stop before completing the last image? Stop during animation of the last image?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple just loop thru all the `<div>`'s

```
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="image"></div>


$('div.image').each(function(){
     // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also select the parent div and loop through all the divs contained within

```
$("#slideshow > div").each(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      if(id == "slide_main"){
           //Do Something
      }  
    }
);
```

This will give the jQuery selector a context and thus will only look for divs within the slideshow div, rather than the whole DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your markup it looks like your doing some sort of slideshow/cycle thing. Any good slideshow/cycle plugin will have callback functions for when certain things happen, so you should pretty easily be able to say something like:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({onChange: function () {
    if ($('#slideshow div:last').is('.active')) {
        $('#slideshow').cyce('stop');
    }
}});
```

Obviously names of classes and callback functions will vary from plugin to plugin.